# XSLT - How to count number of tokens in XML

Tags: xslt, count, token, tokenize

I have a tokenizing template splitting XML element text into HTML dot points. I would like to be able to count the total amount of times the ';' delimiter occurs on specific nodes. How could I go about achieving this?

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="MainNode/Publications/publication_book/text()[normalize-space()]" name="split">
     <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
       <li>
         <xsl:call-template name="telephone">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before(concat($pText, ';'), ';')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </li>
       <xsl:call-template name="split">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="MainNode/Publications/specific_node_that_has_no_li/text()[normalize-space()]" name="telephone">
     <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
     <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
         <xsl:call-template name="replace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before(concat($pText, ';'), ';')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       <xsl:call-template name="telephone">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace">
   <xsl:param name="pText"/>
   <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
        <xsl:call-template name="italic">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before(concat($pText, '*'),'*')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '*')">
           <br/>           
         <xsl:call-template name="replace">
           <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '*')"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="italic">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'^'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $delimiter) and contains(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)">        
                <xsl:call-template name="bold">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before($pText, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            <i>
                <xsl:call-template name="bold">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-before(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </i>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="italic">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="bold">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="bold">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'?'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $delimiter) and contains(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $delimiter)"/>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </b>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="bold">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after(substring-after($pText, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
<xsl:for-each select="MainNode/Publications">

  <!-- The count for number of publication_book which in the example XML is 3 should be outputted here -->

</xsl:for-each>     
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example XML:

```
<MainNode>
<Publications>
        <publication_book>
            ?test?,test., (2012), A new latex price forecasting model to reduce the risk of rubber test in Thailand. ^Handbook on test^*
            ^making:^ Vol 2:^Risk management in test making,^ 33(10), 191-203, New York.;

            test., ?test J.?, Clayden, J., (2010), test Production using Intelligent Time Series Analysis to Support ^Decision^* 
            ^Makers. test Support Systems, Advances In^, 43 ? 56, Croatia.;

            test., Lam, P., ?test.?, Li, H., (2010), test to the Temporal Data-Context of an Alarm of Interest. ^Dynamic and Advanced Data^* 

            ^Mining for test Technological Development: test and Systemic Approaches^, 18-39, USA, test. 
        </publication_book> 
</Publications>
</MainNode>
```

Note: I am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of `li` elements the template creates? Do you want to do that for each matched element separately or for all matched elements?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do this for a selection of matched elements.

Comment: You will need to store the results of applying the template into a variable (which will then hold a result tree fragment) and then you can convert the result tree fragment to a node-set using `exsl:node-set($var)` and count items with e.g. `count(exsl:node-set($var)//li)`. Where and how you do that depends on the structure of the XML and your other XSLT which you have not shared.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to count the total amount of times the ';'
>   token occurs on specific nodes.

I think you mean the ';' *delimiter*, not token. You didn't say how or where you need this, but you can get this number quite easily using:

```
translate($text, translate($text, ';', ''), '')
```

The number of tokens is of course higher by 1, so you would want to use something like:

```
<xsl:template match="current | background | etc.">
    <xsl:variable name="number-of-tokens" select="string-length(translate(., translate(., ';', ''), '')) + 1" />
    <!-- the rest of the template -->
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this occurs within the template matching your list of elements - so each matched element performs its own count.

Comment: So say I have a for each loop below my tokenizing system which is calling the current, background etc to be displayed, I would like to output the count with something like 'This is the total of: count value' at the end of the for each loop. I would also like to output the total of the count outside this for-each loop. The for-each loop is iterating over the parent node of current, background etc.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you're asking here. Your "tokenizing system" writes directly to the output - where exactly is "below" that? Note also that xsl:for each is not a loop.

Comment: Sorry running on not much sleep atm. In my tokenizing system in the original post, there's a for each directly below it in the document structure. I want to output the counts in this for each loop and also outside it so they are displayed in the final HTML with text accompanying them.

Comment: The answer depends on how many descendant nodes a `Publications` node can have. In your example, there is only one, so it's simple. However, if there were two of these, each with 2 delimiters (i.e. 3 tokens), then an answer based on counting (only) the total number of delimiters would be incorrect: there are 4 delimiters, but 6 tokens in total.

Comment: There is multiple descendant nodes for Publications. To avoid this problem, can you instruct the count to add +1 on top of each nodes token count? Then say if I wanted the total publication count of two nodes the count would be correct?

Comment: From the context of `Publications`, all you can do is count the total number of delimiters in **all** of its descendants. Then, if each of these descendants contains at least one token, you can calculate the total number of tokens by adding the count of descendants to the count of the delimiters. If these conditions cannot be guaranteed, you will need a (much) more elaborate method.

Comment: Okay, so just to confirm, I would want the count to only count the total number of delimiters in a select few descendant nodes of a Publications node, leaving multiple descendant nodes with the delimiter being counted out of the count. Would this require a more complex method?

Comment: Sir, Hats-off to your logic for identify particular char count within text, I utilized this logic. Plus one.

Comment: @user2285167 Is this question still open?